# My div's overlap. I want them to be side-by-side, but also responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.box1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left:10%;
  clear: both;
  height: 30%
}

#img1 {
    padding: 5%
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <div class="box1">
        <img id="img1" src="http://i.imgur.com/D5T6lY1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="box1">
        <p style="text-align:left">Choosing a new Point of Sale (POS) is an opportunity. Lavu is not just accepting payments - Lavu is business management on the iPad. Upgrade your business with the Cloud POS system that was developed specifically for the restaurant / hospitality industry. Lavu has the tools you need to improve efficiency and the bottom line. Love your business.</p>
        <div class="rounded-button"> 
            <a href="lavu.com" style="text-decoration: none">live demo<img id="terminal_icon" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZrCANdq.png"/>     </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- I am trying to make a div that holds 2 other divs inside of it.
- I want these 2 divs to be centered on the page.

**Problem** 
I can't keep them from overlapping when I reduce the page width. 
I want the 2 divs inside to *"clear"* each other instead of overlapping *(also to be completely responsive)*. 
I can't seem to achieve this effect. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Your `<p>` tag doesnt have enclosing tag!

Comment: Your fiddle has quite few syntax errors. Here is your version without errors: http://jsfiddle.net/yc3bcLr9/1/

Comment: What is happening is that your image is too large for the div it is inside of and it 'overflows' out of it. Certain elements will behave this way. If you set the image's max-width to 100%, if it is too large for it's parent, it will be resized to fit inside. Simon's and wahwahwah's answers show ways you can do this.

Answer (score 2):

Force the childs of `.box1` to respect the with of their parents with

```
.box1 > * {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.box1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left:10%;
  clear: both;
  height: 30%
}

.box1 > * {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#img1 {
    padding: 5%
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <div class="box1">
        <img id="img1" src="http://i.imgur.com/D5T6lY1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="box1">
        <p style="text-align:left">Choosing a new Point of Sale (POS) is an opportunity. Lavu is not just accepting payments - Lavu is business management on the iPad. Upgrade your business with the Cloud POS system that was developed specifically for the restaurant / hospitality industry. Lavu has the tools you need to improve efficiency and the bottom line. Love your business.</p>
        <div class="rounded-button"> 
            <a href="lavu.com" style="text-decoration: none">live demo<img id="terminal_icon" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZrCANdq.png"/>     </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the image resize in css so to prevent overlapping:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

You might have to play around with the results to get exactly your desired effect as you change resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a framework. The one I'm most familiar with is Twitter Bootstrap. This is how simple your problem would be using that:

```
<div class="container-fluid"> // Create a full-width container
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6"> // 50% Width of the row, made up of 12 Columns
      <img src="..."/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p>Info text about POS System.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div
```

And it would be done. A container that resizes depending on the size of your browser's width, that is centered and does not overlap.

Unfortunately, this is also a bit of an opinion based question, and I don't have a good solution using base CSS.

Hopefully this gives you some insight though. Frameworks are there to make your life simple, and provide easy to use, complaint HTML/CSS layouts.

Cheers!

Comment: Please do not recommend bootstrap! I think its for people who do not want to learn CSS.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with recommending bootstrap... Obviously people should learn CSS, but OP asked for suggestions, I provided one.

Comment: The problem with recommending a framework is that it doesn't answer WHY this issue is occurring. Also, if someone was to implement the code you provided the image would STILL overflow out of its container. http://www.bootply.com/NIvVQlj8Xg

Comment: Well yes, that was just an example. The `img` needs a class, there needs to be a media for `sm`, `md` and `lg` layouts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can to use a `@media` query for make it more responsive, the following jsfiddle demo shows how should be your code: http://jsfiddle.net/zb6xbf8m

Both 'min-width' and 'max-width' properties specified on the `@media` queries is a value that I have defined based on the dimensions of the content of both divs.